# Having problems with music players

Tags: rhythmbox, music, music-player, open-source, amarok

I tried using Rhythmbox, Amarok, Audacious and Foobnix but have the same issue. When I open my computer and try to listen to songs that was on the playlist before, I always get a warning saying 'Resource not found.'; like I changed the path of the songs. I close the application and after around half an hour or longer, I can listen to the songs. I have this problem every time I restart my computer.

I have two partitions in the hard drive and while the program is installed in one, the audio files are in the other partition. This shouldn't be a problem, though, since everyone uses it like this? I am new to Ubuntu and have 14.04 installed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems likely to be a path problem. I would suppose in your music DB the files are referenced like `/dev/sdb2` instead of the mounted path like in `/media/$permanentName`.  Please do a "$ grep location /.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml" to show the file name.